# Getting Examples to look like Theorems/Lemmas/Corollaries

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, theorems

How do you get a latex document to present example in the same bold type face as you can for theorems/lemma/corollaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define general statements as you like; there is no predefined theorem-like environment, because people tend to have different expectations about this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \theoremstyle and proof

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % theorems will be numbered according to section
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma} % lemmas share the counter with theorems
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary} % ditto

\theoremstyle{definition} % body text will be upright
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{A title}

\begin{lem}
This is a lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Here's its proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{exa}
An example to illustrate the theorem.
\end{exa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of choices.  One good one is amsthm.  Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}  
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{exm}{Example}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{thm} \lipsum[2] \end{thm}
\begin{lem} \lipsum[3] \end{lem}
\begin{cor} \lipsum[4] \end{cor}
\begin{exm} \lipsum[5] \end{exm}

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

More packages are on CTAN at http://www.ctan.org/topic/maths-theorem .

Comment: Sorry, you are quite right.  Shouldn't do it between other jobs.  Edited it to put in \begin .. \end's.